# Segfault when assigning to indexed dereferenced pointer to string in c

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, c-strings

The `print` statement executes as expected, and if I print `line[0]` in the `if` statement, it also prints as expected. However, `gdb` tells me there is a `segfault` occuring in that `if` statement. Am I misunderstanding how to access characters in a `string`?

**EDITED CODE TO REMOVE IRRELEVANT ERROR**

```
void setflags(char** linep)
{
  char* line = *linep;
  while(strlen(line))
  {
    printf("%s\n",line);
    if (line[0] == '.') 
      line[0] = '*';
    else if (line[0] == ' ') 
      (*linep) ++;
    else
      break;
    line = *linep;
  }   
}
```

Comment: you forgot to include some sample input that causes the problem.

Comment: `while(strlen(line))` is basically an infinite loop. And you did not show us how `linep` is initialized. You may write to unallocated memory.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that break is pretty much always going to happen, and doesn't strlen return 0 if given a pointer to a location that contains '\0' ?

Comment: @user3504732 The break never happens and the loop is infinite every time the first character is a whitespace. Ex: " hello"

Comment: also true for dot character.

Comment: It would help if you explained what the function is supposed to do. And providing a `main` function that calls `setflags` would also help. See [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: OK i do see the infinite loop issue if the first character is a space, but the loop isn't even executing once. and the first character of the input is a period.

Comment: Then you definitely need to show a minimal example that shows how the function is called, because the code shown will change the dot to a star and return. One possibility is that the caller passes a read-only string, in which case changing the dot to a star in not allowed.

Comment: @user3504732 What do you mean by the loop executing? This program either: 1 - changes the first character to '*' if it's a '.' , then breaks; 2 - enters infinite loop if it's a ' ';  3 - prints the string and breaks if neither.  As long as you're feeding it a pointer to a mutable array and not to a constant string of course.

Comment: OK so I edited the code to try remove the infinite loop thing but that's not really the problem. i'll post a snipped of initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the problematic looping style, your seg fault is not diagnose-able until you show how you're using this function. My suspicions are you passing in a read-only string, such as:

```
char *string = "this is read-only string literal";
setflags(&string); // error
```

If you are doing something like this, you must make it modifiable by using an array:

```
char string[] = "this is a modifiable character array";
setflags(&string); // no error
```